# Using select.getOptions() with Selenium to get values

Tags: java, selenium, windows-7, format

I am using selenium to verify a web site where doctors' names appear in a drop-down box.  If the name in the database has extra spaces (like "Kildare , Jack , MD") the blanks should be removed like "Kildare, Jack MD".  I am using the selenium method select.getOptions() (where select is the web element of a select box).

When I retrieve the date from the box and print it, it shows the names as still having spaces (see Alois Alzheimer and Sigmund Freud below).  In the text box visually it shows Sigmund Freud formatted correctly, but Alois Alzhemier still has a space after Alois (see the attached picture).  I am not sure what is happening here.  Looks like the select box occasionally removes blanks itself and sometimes doesn't.  Any clues?

Here is the debug text from select box:

```
DEBUG [PP21644] ----<Alzheimer, Alois , DO>-----
DEBUG [PP21644] ----<Freud, Sigmund      Schlomo, Jr, MD>-----
DEBUG [PP21644] ----<Mayo, Charles Mayo, MMIN>-----
```

And the picture of how it looks is attached.   Sigmund is formatted correctly but Alois is not (see the space highlighted with a yellow square).  And yes, I had to run this with famous doctors' names to protect the names of the actual providers.

[image]

Comment: I think you are getting back a String and printing it. If thats the case then you should be able to use `string.trim()`. You may also want to look into `string.split(",")` before doing a `trim()`.

Comment: What does the HTML of the `OPTION`s look like? My guess is that there are some HTML tags between the name parts that is causing all the extra spaces. Either that or they aren't cleaning the names properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this

1. You could examine the HTML of the `OPTION`s and figure out where the spaces are coming from, parse it, etc. to get rid of the spaces. I can't really offer code here since I don't know what the HTML looks like.
2. Another way given what you provided is to use regex and `.replace()` to remove repeated spaces and to remove a space before a comma.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       String s1 = "Alzheimer, Alois , DO";
       String s2 = "Freud, Sigmund      Schlomo, Jr, MD";
       String s3 = "Mayo, Charles Mayo, MMIN";
       System.out.println(cleanup(s1));
       System.out.println(cleanup(s2));
       System.out.println(cleanup(s3));
   }
   public static String cleanup(String s)
   {
       return s.replaceAll(" +", " ").replace(" ,", ",");
   }
   ```

Comment: Not sure what happened to my comment.  Eliminating extra spaces is ok, but not space after comma.  In that case the developers need to fix.

Comment: This doesn't remove space *after* comma... only space before.